# Waiting time in Queue with $N$ policy

Tags: queueing-theory

> Suppose that a queue has $N$-policy, that is, only when there are $N$ customers in the queue the service starts. In such a queue with deterministic arrival rate $\lambda$ and deterministic service rate $\mu$ (Nothing is stochastic here and inter arrival time is more than service time),
>   (a) what will be the waiting time of all the customers (from the time of start of service) until the queue size is zero for the first time?
>   (b) In how much time, will the queue be of size zero for the first time?

The waiting time of the $N$ customers is easy to figure out:
$$\frac{N(N+1)}{2\mu}.$$ The rest am not sure about. Kindly help me with the two questions.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am unsure what is exactly asked in (a) and (b). In (a), is it the time to go from $N$ customers to $0$ customers? In (b), is it the time to go from $0$ to $0$ customers?

Comment: (b) is the time for going from $N$ customers to $0$ customers. (a) is the sum of waiting time of each of the customers from the time the service starts (when there are $N$ customers waiting) till the time the service ends (the first time there are $0$ customers in the system).

Answer (score 2):

The upward arrows denote arrival while he downward arrows denote departure. Both arrivals and departures happen at every $\kappa \tau $ time units from the start of the service (as well at every time unit which is L.C.M. of $\kappa$ and $\tau$). In between all multiples of $\kappa \tau $ the queue length shrinks by $\kappa - \tau $ units, till it becomes $0$. The time between the start of the service till the queue is of size $0$ for the first time since the start of the service will be:
$$\frac{\kappa \tau (N-1)}{\kappa - \tau} + \tau = \frac{(N-1)}{\mu - \lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu}$$

To calculate the total backlogging cost during the service period, let:
\begin{align*}
\kappa &= a \alpha \\
\tau &= a \beta 
\end{align*}
where $a$ is the G.C.D. of $\kappa$ and $\tau$. Let $t_1, t_2, \dots , t_n $ be multiples of $a$ where $ t_n = \frac{\kappa \tau (N-1)}{\kappa - \tau} $ and $n = N-1$. Between every $t_i$ and $t_{i-1}, (1<i<N+1)$  each arrival will find the same queue length, hence the waiting time for all such arrivals will be equal. The number of arrivals between each  $t_i$ and $t_{i-1}$ will be $(\alpha - \beta)$.\
The demands that are generated at $t_1, t_2, \dots , t_n $ will find the queue of length $(N-1), \dots, 1$ respectively at the time of arrival.
The total backlogging cost of all the demands that are generated during the service period will be :-
\begin{equation*}
\textit{Backlogging $Cost_S$/Inner Cycle} =  \frac{N(N-1)}{2 \mu}    (\alpha - \beta +1) \pi   
\end{equation*}

[image: Graph]